# SWIFT Specs - What is the difference between a field and a tag?

Tags: swift-mt

Could someone please give me an explanation on what exactly the difference between a SWIFT field and a SWIFT tag is? When looking at an example it is first listed as a tag:

[image]

When clicking on "Start of Block" link to see details for tag 16R it is referred to as a field:

[image]

These screenshots are taken from an MT527 message. Is there some difference between these two terms or not?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field generally refers to the complete fields with its name and value. While the tag usually refers to the name of the field, including the number and optional letter option.

However, in many places you will find that the terms are used interchangeably.